# How to Test Windows Device Drivers

Tags: windows, device-driver

Any standarda tools and Techniques that are available for window driver testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a few, which you would find straight from the documentation.

[DriverVerifier](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/tools/DrvVerifier.mspx) is a great tool, I've had less success with the  [Static verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/tools/sdv.mspx) but I suppose it works just as well.
[This](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/tools/default.mspx) web page on MSDN is probably a good summary of existing tools. I'd also add checking your drivers on [Checked builds](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/tools/chkblds.mspx) of Windows to work on timing bugs. Checked builds also generally have easier to read stack traces.

If security is your thing then [Grey Hat Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271921) has a chapter devoted to fuzzing drivers.

EDIT: About your comment. Microsoft has a full set of articles on testing different filter drivers. Keyboards for example are covered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961439.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for responding. This sets the right direction for me. What I am basically looking for is some thoughts on testing filter drivers for devices like Keyboard and mouse developed for windows Servers. I will go through these tools you specified.

Comment: Edited my answer to contain information that may be relevant for you.